# Generating separate "model" classes from a WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, model, svcutil.exe

I'd like to be able to generate individual classes (one class per file) for each Data Contract or XML type in a WCF Web Service.

I've read the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) documentation, and unless I skimmed a little too fast, it doesn't look like the tool supports this behaviour.

The reason I want to do this is simple - I'm trying to isolate the service's "model" from the service itself.  There are several components that rely on types from the service, but don't care about the details of service-level operations such as loading/saving.  I don't like the fact that these components need to take on dependencies to the same assembly that contains all sorts of invocation and binding logic.

I know that `svcutil` (and the VS integration) can be configured to use pre-existing model classes in another assembly.  This is a chicken-and-egg problem though; I don't really want to have to write 50 classes by hand that are (at least for now) almost identical to the generated classes.  And of course I have to add all the `DataContract` attributes with namespaces and other WCF attributes... it's a pain.

My ultimate aim is to actually have a presentation/domain model that's completely independent of the service model, but I don't really have the cycles for that yet.  I think that generating a faux-model that can eventually be molded into a genuine presentation model would be a good, quick and easy way to start down this path.  After that, I can configure the service references to use the separately-generated proxy classes and begin fleshing out something more robust.

Can this be done?  Are there options for `svcutil` that will get it to generate one class per file?  Or is there another tool that can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tool that would support this at this time - I'd love to know about such a tool myself, if it exists!

If you have the cycles to attack this yourself, you could

- grab the service's WSDL from a URL (or load it from a file)
- parse out the XML classes defined in the embedded XML schema
- use something like T4 templates or another mechanism to generate C# code from those XML schemas

It's definitely possible - and probably not even really all that hard - but who's got the time to do it?? :-)